# How to customize Hyperledger Fabric test network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am currently working at a blockchain project with Hyperledger Fabric, and I'm facing some issues.

The scenario I would like to achieve is the following:

- three organizations (Org1, Org2, Org3) with one peer each
- a private channel between Org1 and Org2, say channel12
- a private channel between Org2 and Org3, say channel23

My problem is that I can't understand how to customize the provided Hyperledger Fabric test network, in order to achieve the described scenario.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Maybe minifab can get you started https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/minifabric

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the configuration of the test network in configtx.yaml (test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml). I would start by adding a definition for Org3, which you can model off the existing definitions for Org1 and Org2 under the Organizations section, then creating a new channel profile that includes (Org2, Org3) under the Profiles section.

If by private channel you mean:

There is a need to encapsulate all the attributes of a channel like the chaincode deployed and the peers on the channel. In this case, you can use the createChannel.sh script (test-network/scripts/createChannel.sh) to join Org1 and Org2 to a new channel, then use this script as a base for another script joining Org2 and Org3 to another channel, referencing the new channel profile created earlier.

There is a need to keep only the data within transactions private. In this case, a separate channel for Org2 and Org3 would be unnecessary. You can use the [addOrg3 script](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network/addOrg3) to create and add Org3 to an existing channel between Org1 and Org2. You can then use [private data](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private_data_tutorial.html#pd-use-case) to hide the data in transactions on the channel.